# Java converting from Object to Subclass

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance, types

Here is my code for Scene.java. It has different types of objects, all of which are included in one common ArrayList called `targets`. All of them share a `toString()` method that returns their identifier. I want to use the `targets` list to determine if there is any object in the scene that matches a given identifier, regardless of its type:

```
ArrayList<NPC> npcs = new ArrayList<NPC>();
ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
ArrayList<EnviromentalObject> enviromental_objects = new ArrayList<EnviromentalObject>();

ArrayList<Object> targets;

public Object check_for_target(String target_name){
    targets.addAll(npcs);
    targets.addAll(items);
    targets.addAll(enviromental_objects);
    for (Object target : targets){
        if (target.toString() == target_name){
            return target;
        }
    }
    return null;
```

Here is the code in Game.java, which checks for a given identifier. If there is a match ion the current scene, I want to know the object's type and treat it as its true type. Right now, I have the following code, and I knew it wouldn't work, but maybe it'll help get my idea across.

```
Object target = current_scene.check_for_target(target_name);
        if (target == null){
            System.out.println(UNRECOGNIZED_TARGET_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            String target_type = target.getClass().getName();
            target = (target_type) target;
        }
```

What would be the correct way of getting the object's type and then being able to use that object's methods? Right now, I'm only given `Object`'s methods. Do I create a superclass for `NPC`, `Item`, and `EnviromentalObject`?

Comment: An aside: `if (target.toString() == target_name){` --> That line is going to give you some troubles. Use .equals() for objects.

Comment: You can use the `instanceof` keyword to check an object's type.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but more general... You're using a `List` of `Item`s which is a separate issue from your chosen List implementation of `ArrayList`, so you should declare `List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();` -- note also you don't have to repeat `<Item>` on the right-hand-side. This way, if you later decide a `LinkedList` works better you don't have to redeclare everything.

Comment: While using `instanceof` does indeed discover the type, it is a non-OO way of working — it breaks encapsulation; it breaks polymorphism.  It is a correct answer to _"Java converting from Object to Subclass"_, but is a poor approach. Learn to use _interfaces_. Perhaps NPC, Item, and EnvironmentalObject are all `Targetable`, and NPC & Item are `Moveable` while the EnvironmentalObject is not. Then `findTarget(target_name)` would return a `Targetable` instead of an `Object`.

Comment: define `treat it as its true type`. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: @StephenP: Please explain.

Comment: Suppose you could do `target = (target_type) target;`... what good does that do you, when `target` is still a variable of type reference to `Object`?

Comment: @moonman239: while I'd love to explain, my little comment above could be the subject of an entire textbook on OO techniques, or a full tutorial on [programming with interfaces](https://www.google.com/#q=programming+with+interfaces) — not really appropriate for an SO comment thread and wouldn't fit anyway.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Basically, you can check if an object is an instance of a specific class.

it could be something like this :

```
if( target instanceof NPC) {
    System.out.println("target  is a NPC");
}
else if( Target instanceof Item) {
    System.out.println("target is an Item");
}

if( target  instanceof EnviromentalObject) {

    System.out.println("target is EnviromentalObject"); 
}
```

Edit: as we talked in the comments I think you can change your code to reach a better solution. The above code is still works but it can be a very good practice to using **Design Patterns** that are known as best practices in programming. For this situation think about using java interface and define share methods that each object could implements them by its need. In the simplest way they print their identifier. Let's use an example :

```
public interface SceneThings() {

    public void printIdentifire();

    public String doSomeOtherThings();

}
```

Each object can implements the above interface by it needs like :

```
public class Item implements SceneThing {

...

public void printIdentifire(){

//print its identifier here.
System.out.print("ID:ITEM###");

}

public String doSomeOtherThings(){

    //do some other works !!!
}
...
}
```

for other items same as above. And then you can use a single array to keep them without worry about their origin class like this:

```
ArrayList<SceneThings> targets = new ...

SceneThing  obj = new Item();
targets.add(obj);
```

I hope this can help you to define a better solution in your case.

Comment: Thanks a bunch mate

Comment: While this will work, in general it's considered a code smell, if not an anti-pattern.  You really should create an interface that all of your classes implement that includes the shared functionality.

Comment: There are only a few situations (like in an `equals` implementation) in which using `instanceof` is a good thing - mostly because you have no other choice. This is none of them.

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle Why is it a bad thing? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @IanMcLaird yeah I agree with you, at top level for a better solution maybe it can be a good choice to use **design patterns**, but I just consider the situation and the current need of the question.

Comment: @SeanScott Well, assume the number of classes which can be targets grows over the time. Then you will have to add more and more `if(target instanceOf SomeClass)` statements, which makes maintaining really hard. Using an interface or an abstract class, you don't have to touch this again.

Comment: Also, consider that the number of classes may grow *externally*.  Using this implementation, only *you* can add new classes.  Somebody downstream in the future can't extend your code.  This violates the Open/Closed Principle.

Answer (score 7):

One of the ways how it could be done it to declare a superclass or interface `Target` and use it to keep targets array, the full code sample with abstract class:

```
ArrayList<NPC> npcs = new ArrayList<NPC>();
ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
ArrayList<EnviromentalObject> enviromental_objects = new ArrayList<EnviromentalObject>();

ArrayList<Target> targets;

public Target check_for_target(String target_name) {
    targets.addAll(npcs);
    targets.addAll(items);
    targets.addAll(enviromental_objects);
    for (Target target : targets) {
        if (target.toString().equals(target_name)) {
            return target;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private abstract class Target {}
private class NPC extends Target {}
private class Item extends Target {}
private class EnviromentalObject extends Target {}
```

Comment: I almost agree (see my comment on the Q) but would use Interfaces rather than a superclass. Upvoting anyway because this is a better approach than endless `instanceof`s.

Comment: @StephenP yes, your point is right, the interface might be more applicable here, but abstract class is also valid design. The information in the question is not enough to determine that, but I'll update the answer to mention about the interface as well, thanks

Comment: It's always better to use an interface than an abstract class, if the interface will do an adequate job, since in Java you only get to extend *one* class, but you can implement as many interfaces as you want.